# $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid X=x]]$

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

By the law of total expectation, $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid Y]]$ for any random variables $X,Y$.

What if we replace "$Y$" with "$X=x$", where $x\in\mathbb R$ is arbitrary? Something must go wrong somewhere because this leads to

$\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid X=x]]=\mathbb E[x]=x, \forall x\in \mathbb R$.

**Edit**: Actually I remember one course where $E[X\mid Y]$ was defined in terms of $E[X\mid Y=y]$ (and not the other way around). The definition of $E[X\mid Y=y]$ was a function $\varphi=\varphi(y)$ satisfying some constraint (will write it here once I find my notes), and $E[X\mid Y]$ was defined as the function $\varphi$ evaluated at $Y$.

What can be said about $\mathbb E[X\mid Y,Z=z]$?

Comment: Is this well possed? Fix $x$, then $X \mid X = x$ is a constant random variable, with value $x$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X \mid X = x] = x$. Note that this is not a random variable, but a constant. Then, how is it $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid X = x]] = \mathbb{E}[x]$ defined?

Comment: The mistake is in assuming that $E[X] = E[E[X\mid X=x]]$.

Comment: If we replace $Y$ by $X=x$ (as you suggest) then we replace a random variable by an event. That is "fatal" for good understanding of the notation.

Comment: In the law of total expectation $E(X|Y)$ is  random variable measurable w.r.t $\sigma (Y)$. According to the general definition of conditional expectation it is not true that $E(X|X=x)$ is the real number $x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: If the event $\{X=x\}$ has positive probability, then it certainly is true. What else would it be?

Comment: @StefanHansen Its is the random variable which has the value $x$ on the set $\{X=x\}$ and the value $E(XI_{X\neq x})/P(X \neq x)$ on the set $X \neq x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: $E[X\mid X=x]$ is not a random variable (well yes it is, but it's a constant one).

Comment: The problem here is there is  slight conflict of notations. If you want to use the formula $E(E(X|Y))=EY$ you cannot use your definition of $E(X|X=x)$. @StefanHansen

Comment: Right, that's the core of it but it's misleading to say $E[X\mid X=x]$ should be anything else than $x$.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is in assuming that $\mathrm{E}[Y]=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X=x]]$. What holds is the tower property which states that  $\mathrm{E}[Y]=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X]]$.

So the mistake is in assuming that the two objects $\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X]$ and $\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X=x]$ are interchangeable -- which they are not. Instead there's the connection that if we call $\varphi(x)=\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X=x]$, then $\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X]=\varphi(X)$. So indeed $\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X]$ is a random variable (measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$) whereas $\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X=x]$ is just a constant.